# Populating a second sheet with data from the first sheet based on an entered date

Tags: microsoft-excel

Sheet one is cumulative over many months with a column for date.

Example:

```
  A    |    B     |   C   |   D    
 Date  | Location | Start | Stop    
1/2/18 |   b-4    |   5   |   6    
1/2/18 |   b-5    |   6   |   7    
1/3/18 |   a-4    |   5   |   6
```

Sheet 2 is generally blank and used to provide daily information to a client. I need to type the date at the top and have it populate all information from that date. It can stay blank until I type in the date.

Example of the result:

```
Date: 1/2/18

   A     |   B   |   C  
Location | Start | Stop
  b-4    |   5   |   6
  b-5    |   6   |   7
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use an advanced filter.

Comment: You could set a cell with =DATE to always return today's date. Then use a SUMIF or INDEX MATCH approach to populate the 2nd sheet. The summary table would reference the date cell and look up the values associated with it in the main sheet

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**How it works:**

1. In Cell **A2 of Sheet 2** write caption **Date**.
2. And in Cell **B2 of Sheet 2** enter any of the dates available in **Column
   A(Date Column)  of Sheet 1**.
3. Create **Helper Column in Sheet1** and write this Formula in **cell E3** & 
   fill it down.

   `=IF(A3=Sheet2!$B$2,1+MAX($E$2:E2),"")` .

Write this formula in cell **A4 of Sheet 2** & fill right then down.

```
`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),Sheet1!$E:$E,0)),"")`
```

*You get desire records in Sheet 2, as shown in screen shot.*